# Driving Directions in the map

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I have a view based application and in that I want to show driving directions on map.
I searched for it on google, I got the google maps driving directions api but I didn't got how to use it in program directly webview or is there any other way to use that api programmatically. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want my advice (and this is the way I do things), use an UIWebView and use a Javascript-based sample to to ask Google to draw directions for you.
It's easy!

Comment: Yes you can find many tutorials starting from the Google Map Javascript API http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/. For a working sample, try this http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-directions/draggable-directions.html. I use this semplified version: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drivingdirections/directions-optimized.html

Comment: I tried to find out but I got the half way on this http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone.html Will you plese help me where to place html file or from where we will get it.....?

Comment: take the file from here http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drivingdirections/directions-optimized.html then change the origin and destination values with some foo placeholders. In your code load the file NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"directions" ofType:@"html"];  NSString *contentFile4 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
then replace with your coord NSString *contentFile3 = [contentFile4 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"foolatitude" withString:withLat]; finally load the string inside the webview

Answer (score 2):

Use this link:
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&saddr=25.612524,85.128281&daddr=28.574815,77.236545&output=kml
or
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&saddr=patna&daddr=new+delhi&output=kml

You can use both  web services, one with lat and long ,where second one is with saddr(source address) and daddr(destination address). It gives you xml file parse it and make array of intermediately lat-long points . I think u know how to draw route on MKMapView with the help of Overlay class.

**If you need to finding lat long of given name of location ,use this link:
http://maps.google.co.in/maps?t=h&z=10&hl=en&format=p&q=new+delhi&output=kml 
**Keep in mind that ,if location name have two or more then two words then it combines with + operator.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at `MKMapViewController` for displaying maps. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136) on how to draw routes with `MKPolyline`.